# How do I find out which websites are slowing down my server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance-monitoring, resources, monitoring

Are there any good tools out there that I can use to find out which websites are the biggest drain on my Windows 2003 web server's resources? The server has been steadily slowing to a crawl and I want to know which sites should get priority for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows the only good way to find out (known to me) is to set an application pool for every site.

By default everything is within a default application pool.
Once they have their own application pool, they also have their own process.

Having their own process will show you which one is taking all the ressources within the task manager.

Good luck.

Comment: Itis also most sensible (ESPECIALLY on 2008 - you should upgrade) to isolate the websites.

Comment: Thanks, that makes so much sense. We already have our sites in separate application pools. I will use that.